# How to automatically separate a list of tuples

Tags: python

I have a list like this:

```
a = [(a, b), (c, i), (d, i), (e, b), (f, b), (g, i)]
```

I want to separate this list of tuples where the element `b` exists. The outcome should look like this:

```
a = [[(a, b), (c, i), (d, i)], [(e, b)], [(f, b), (g ,i)]]
```

Is there any way I could do this?

Comment: is your output not identical to your input?

Comment: no no no that was a mistke sorry

Comment: It's not clear how the output relates to the input.

Comment: what if the first tuple doesn't contain element b?

Comment: If the first tuple doesn't have a `b` in it, should it be discarded? Should `[(a,a), (a,b)]` be `[[(a,a)], [(a,b)]]` or `[ [(a,b)]]`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
def group_b(arr):
    b_in_group = False
    grouped = []
    group = []
    for tup in arr:
        if "b" in tup:
            if not b_in_group:
                group.append(tup)
                b_in_group = True
            else:
                if group:
                    grouped.append(group)

                group = [tup]
        else:
            group.append(tup)

    grouped.append(group)

    return grouped

print (group_b([("a", "b"), ("c", "i"), ("d", "i"), ("e", "b"), ("f", "b"), ("g", "i")]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you start your output as a list with a single sublist in it, you know that the insertion point is always the last sublist in the list. Whenever you see the test data, append a new empty list.

```
a = 'a'
b = 'b'
c = 'c'
d = 'd'
e = 'e'
f = 'f'
g = 'g'
h = 'h'
i = 'i'

# input list
in_list = [(a,b),(c,i),(d,i),(e,b),(f,b),(g,i)]

# output
out = [[]]

for tpl in in_list:
    if b in tpl:
        # if existing list has data, push empty list on end
        if out[-1]:
            out.append([])
    out[-1].append(tpl)

print(out)
```